# Finding power series expansion at a point that is not 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I want to find the power series expansion of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ at $z=2$. I tried to separate the $z(\frac{1}{(1-z)^2})$ and $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ is just the geometric series of $\sum kz^{k-1}$ but for it to centered at $z=2$, it needs to be $\frac{z}{(1-(z-2))^2}$. How do I manipulate this to become something like that?

From the posts I saw here with (but with first power at denominator), I see them doing $\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{-1-(z-2)} = \frac{-1}{1+(z-2)}$ so it can be writtern as a geometric series, but this manipulation is without the second power? How can I proceed with the second power?

Comment: Let $z=x+2$ and work around $x=0$

Comment: Expand $(-1)/(1-(2-z))$ into the sum of geometric progression, take a derivative and at the end multiply by $2+(z-2).$ In this way you avoid raising the series to the second power.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici then it becomes $\frac{1}{(-(1-(-x)))^2}$ but there is still a negative in front of the thing, how do I get rid if the negative to put it in a formula of geomtric series centered at $x = 0$?

Comment: It becomes $$\frac{x+2}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{x+1+1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac 1{x+1}+\frac 1{(x+1)^2}=\frac 1{x+1}-\frac d{dx} \frac 1{x+1}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici shit thank you I don't know you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}}&=\frac{z}{\left(1+(z-2)\right)^2}\\
> &=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}(z-2)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\left((z-2)+2\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)(z-2)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)(z-2)^{n+1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)(z-2)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n(z-2)^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)(z-2)^n\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+2)(z-2)^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we shift the index of the left-hand series by one to start with $n=1$.